# Passing Data Via NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` embed in with a `UINavigationController`. I want to present this `viewController` and after presenting I also need Navigation method (Push & Pop) so I am presenting `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewController` but for that I need to pass custom data to that `ViewController` as of I have no access to that `ViewController` form previous `ViewController`.
Here is my code.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNavigationIdentity"]];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> P.S I cannot `alloc` and `init` new `navigationController` as I am designing my navigationController from Storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access your `viewController` from `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController`.

```
if (navigationController.viewControllers.count > 0) {
     //Cast UIViewController with your custom Controller
     ViewController *vc = (ViewController*) [navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
     //Now pass data you want
     vc.passData = ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply access the `ViewController` embed inside your `UINavigationController` using the `childViewControllers` property

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [navigationController childViewControllers];
if (viewControllers.count > 0) {
    UIViewController *myViewController = (UIViewController *)[viewControllers firstObject];
}
```